# Two ETL on same source data at same time

Tags: oracle, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

Sorry the really newbie question but I want to get a simple answer.

We have our data come in to us and it gets stored as raw data. Currently we have an ICT team who have produced an ETL process that does a lot of work turning it into something usable for analysis but this takes a lot of time. The issue is that the time taken means that the data quality report that needs to go back is often late and prevents issues from being resolved. As DQ needs to be done on raw data and not cleaned, can I run build a second ETL process to create the DQ tables.

By this I mean can they both be run simultaneously as the main ETL will be an Oracle process using the raw data as a data source and the one I want to build will also use raw data in Oracle as a data source using SSIS.

I know it's probably a simple question, but as it's not something I do on a day to day basis so I don't know if it can be done this way or if one will have to wait until the other has finished.

We are storing the data in Oracle 11g and doing the major process there. I'll be using SQL 2008 R2 to what I want.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I suppose that would depend on whether the Oracle process obtains locks on the raw data and what kind of locks it uses.  If you are already using Oracle to import the raw data into SQL and process it, what are you hoping that SQL server will do differently?  Just process faster?

Comment: Thanks Eric. That's exactly what I need to know. I need to ask about locks otherwise I'll need to make sure it goes before. The issue is that Oracle ETL takes about a week to complete all it's processing, data cleaning, sign off, cloning etc. and what is needed a very simple summary table ASAP to do DQ but the ICT team do not have time to do it so it has been thrown at me to look at. All I have access to tool wise is SQL. Currently DQ can't be done until after the full processing has occurred.

Comment: A week?  That's easily the longest run time I've heard of in a production environment.  Good luck.

Comment: Quite possibly. It was an ETL that was originally done by another company that contractors then brought in house. The plan is, once IT have the time, to re-write it but they are still fixing issues that have arisen from the migration whilst catching up on the backlog of change requests. Thanks again.

Comment: Personally i wouldn't try to intervene with a process that takes a week (wow!) - i hope those contractors didn't get paid too much!  How many rows are we talking about?  I normally toss around ~30 million rows and run my ETL hourly - including Data Quality checks